# Throw Error: Describe is not a function. Getting this error while running Mocha Test

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js, ui-automation

[image: Throw Err Errtype: describe is not a function.]

I have installed the mocha but while running this test using command then getting describe is not a function error.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the mocha functions `describe`, `before`, `after` and `it` in line 2 of your script. I don't know how selenium is handling this, but I would try this:

- Comment line 2
- Run `mocha mochaTest.js` again -> Error should disappear

Next you should uncomment line 2 again and see if `selenium-webdriver/testing` is installed properly.